# EF - Item Removed From Collection But Not From Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Running into this strange issue. I'm using the following code to manage a collection from a form:

```
    public void UpdateLinks(EventViewModel form)
    {
        var selectedIds = form.Links.Select(r => r.ResourceTypeID).ToList();
        var assignedIds = form.Event.Links.Select(r => r.ResourceTypeID).ToList();
        foreach (var resource in form.Links)
        {
            resource.EventID = form.Event.ID;
            if (!assignedIds.Contains(resource.ResourceTypeID))
                form.Event.Links.Add(resource);
        }
        foreach (var resource in form.Event.Links.ToList())
        {
            if (!selectedIds.Contains(resource.ResourceTypeID))
                form.Event.Links.Remove(resource);
        }
    }
```

The code is successfully updating the Links collection and this is reflected correctly in the view, however it is not removing the child record from the database table. That means if I remove a collection item and then go to add one again that would have the same composite key, the following exception is thrown:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK_dbo.EventResource'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.EventResource'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1). The
>   statement has been terminated.

Other pertinent info:

**EVENT CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EventViewModel form, HttpPostedFileBase[] eventFiles)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        eventsService.UpdateEvent(form.Event);
        eventsService.UpdateManufacturerTags(form);
        eventsService.UpdateFiles(form, eventFiles);
        eventsService.UpdateLinks(form);
        eventsService.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = form.Event.ID });
    }
    return View(form);
}
```

**EVENT**

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Start Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:M/d/yyyy h:mm tt}")]
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("End Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:M/d/yyyy h:mm tt}")]
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }

    public string Venue { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Registration Link")]
    public string RegistrationUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<EventResource> Files { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<EventResource> Links { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<EventResource> Resources
    {
        get { return Files.Concat(Links); }
    }

    public string LongStartDate
    {
        get { return StartTime.Value.ToLongDateString(); }
    }

    public string ShortStartDate
    {
        get { return StartTime.Value.ToShortDateString(); }
    }

    public string ShortStartTime
    {
        get { return StartTime.Value.ToShortTimeString(); }
    }

    public string LongEndDate
    {
        get { return EndTime.Value.ToLongDateString(); }
    }

    public string ShortEndDate
    {
        get { return EndTime.Value.ToShortDateString(); }
    }

    public string ShortEndTime
    {
        get { return EndTime.Value.ToShortTimeString(); }
    }

    public Event()
    {
        Manufacturers = new List<Manufacturer>();
        Files = new List<EventResource>();
        Links = new List<EventResource>();
    }
}
```

**EVENT RESOURCE**

```
public class EventResource
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ResourceTypeID { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    public virtual ResourceType Type { get; set; }
}
```

**RESOURCE TYPE**

```
public class ResourceType
{   
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**PERTINENT LINES FROM CONTEXT CLASS**

```
public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
public DbSet<EventResource> EventResources { get; set; }
public DbSet<ResourceType> ResourceTypes { get; set; }
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.EventResource'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventResource'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1). The statement has been terminated.]    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1788622    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
+5377458    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +269    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1406    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +205    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160    System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +535    System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) +262

[UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]    System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) +444    System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache) +146    System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
+571    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +114

[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.]    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +200    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +33    System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +20    PennLighting.DAL.EventsService.Save() in c:\Users\Dom\Documents\GitHub\PennLighting\PennLighting\DAL\Services\EventsService.cs:164 PennLighting.Controllers.EventsController.Edit(EventViewModel form, HttpPostedFileBase[] eventFiles) in c:\Users\Dom\Documents\GitHub\PennLighting\PennLighting\Controllers\EventsController.cs:146 lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +125    System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14    System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
+28    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
_) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
+58    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
+225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
+50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
+24    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
+50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
+31    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
+9657028    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18213
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't call SaveChanges.

Comment: I do use SaveChanges... I posted a method from my service, which is used by my controller during the update process. Like I said, I can add and remove items, but because they are never removed from the database, I end up running into duplicate PK errors.

Comment: I suggest to remove and call SaveChanges() before you insert something.

Comment: So Save before updating the collection?

Comment: yes try that what happens.

Comment: When I said you should replace the quote with a code block I did not mean just swap the two by pressing the buttons, because you did your first post as a quote you lost all of the new lines. you need to delete the text here, replace it with a new copy of the text that is properly formatted, then highlight it and press the code button.

Comment: Hey Scott - DealWithIt.gif. The StackTrack really isn't useful in this case anyway. I know what the error means - a duplicate key. It doesn't explain why things are staying in the database after they are removed from a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
form.Event.Links.Remove(resource);
```

To

```
context.EventResources.Remove(resource);
```

And now it works... weird that I don't have to do this on any other part of the site where I manage collections the same way but so be it.

Comment: It works because they are both different `DbContext` objects, saving on one `DbContext` doesn't save on the other. i.e. List<string> ListA calling ListA.Add() does not add anything to List<string> ListB, so when you remove from the `form.DbContext`, it isn't removed in the `DbContext `EventResources`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that Bob. Will have to take this approach going forward.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you remove something from collection you should call `form.SaveChanges()`. Make sure when you call SaveChanges() entities must be deleted first before you insert something.

Comment: I do use SaveChanges... I posted a method from my service, which is used by my controller during the update process. Like I said, I can add and remove items, but because they are never removed from the database, I end up running into duplicate PK errors. I just updated the original post to show my Controller method.